# Does jquery event handling code needs null check or unidentified check?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("input[name='SOME_ID']").on('input propertychange',function(){
    doCalculateDuration();
});
```

Do I need to check that html of id `SOME_ID` exists before running this code to prevent js errors ?

Comment: The answer is _No_

Comment: and long one ? :)

Comment: you dont need to check anything..it wont execute if the html element doesnot exist

Comment: @osamayaccoub long answer: Nooooooooo

Comment: :) .... I mean when exactly do I need to do such checks in jquery and when no ?

Comment: When working with event handlers as above, then you don't need to worry about it as the event will only be bound if the element exists. It's more of an issue when retrieving attributes/properties from elements. Eg `var foo = $('#bar').text()`. That won't throw an error is `#bar` doesn't exist, but if you're expecting the `foo` to always be set then you will have a problem.

Comment: isn't "retreiving attributes/properties" include `$('#bar').text()` ???